# How to access form data in custom components in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, react-final-form

I need to change the behaviour of a toolbar button depending on a status field of the form.
I don't know how to get access to the current form data to read the status value.

I tried with `FormDataConsumer` in the surrounding component (`Toolbar` in my case) and pass formData as a prop, but that had the side effect that `handleSubmitWithRedirect` inside the button did not work.

I'd like to read form data directly inside the button component. How can I do this?

The current code:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const StatusButton= ({ handleSubmitWithRedirect, ...props }) => {
    const form = useForm();

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        switch (props.formdata.status.id) {   
            case 0:
                form.change('status', status[1]);
                break;
            case 1:
                form.change('status', status[2]);
                break;
            default:
        }
        handleSubmitWithRedirect('list');
    }, [form]);

    return <SaveButton {...props} handleSubmitWithRedirect={handleClick} />;
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export const MyToolbar= props => (
    <Toolbar {...props} >
        <SaveButton
            label="Speichern"
            redirect="list"
            submitOnEnter={true}
            variant="text"
        />

        <FormDataConsumer>
            {({ formData, ...rest }) =>
                <StatusButton
                    label="Statuswechsel"
                    redirect="list"
                    submitOnEnter={false}
                    variant="text"
                    formdata={formData}  
                />
            }
        </FormDataConsumer>
    </Toolbar>
);
```

Update:
you can see an example in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-accessformdata-v0uq7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&initialpath=%23%2Fposts%2F1%2Fshow&module=%2Fsrc%2Fposts%2FPostShow.js&theme=dark

Comment: not sure about intentions ... `useForm` and <FormDataConsumer/> does the same, brings context ... for `useForm` you get `form` - from docs - allows API access ... then looks it should be `form.getStatus().values` ?

Comment: 'status' is a custom form field which in my case contains an id-name tuple object. I could not find any hints in the documententation how to access the form data using 'form'.

Comment: `form.getStatus().values.status` ? .... get `form.getStatus()` into some var and inspect using debugger/dev tools?  .... prepare [mcve]

Comment: the intention is to check the current workflow step (called status in my case), not the technical status of the form

Comment: there is no form.getStatus()

Comment: prepare [example]

Comment: useForm is a react hook from the react-final-form library and it returns a <Form/> componet which does not seem to support accessing the field contents (at least this is how it looks to me). 

It's hard to prepare minimal reproducable example because of all the dependencies. For an expert on react-admin or react-final-form my question ist presumably pretty trivial.

Comment: minimal = w/o react-admin ... just a similiar structure to your parts

Comment: I added a codesandbox :)

Comment: found it: it's actually ````form.getState().values````

Comment: then I didn't read carefully ... I'm from Formik club ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field values of the current form can be read accessed this:

```
import { useForm } from 'react-final-form';

const form = useForm();
var formdata = form.getState().values;
```

`formdata` contains the whole form values as an object.